# how to add primary key to realm objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, primary-key

I am trying to make my realm objects able to edit from the app. This is my class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Category: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let items = List<Item>()
}
```

this is how I make instances of that class:

```
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { action in
            
            let newCategory = Category()
            newCategory.name = textField.text!
            
            self.save(category: newCategory)
        }
```

this is my edit method:

```
func edit(category: Category) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(category, update: .all)
            }
        }catch {
            print("error editing category \(error)")
        }
    }
```

and this is how I call my edit method inside IBAction for when edit button pressed

```
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save Changes", style: .default) { action in
            
            let editedCategory = Category()
            editedCategory.name = textField.text!
            
            self.edit(category: editedCategory)

        }
```

the error I am getting is: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''Category' does not have a primary key and can not be updated'"

I have tried adding the primary key in my category class, but is still did not work. Any help?

Comment: Did you override the primaryKey func? Follow the docs: https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-primary-keys-tutorial/

Comment: Can you please elaborate how did you add primary key in category class and it still doesn't work? Please update your code example with primary key added

Comment: You do not need a primary key. It is entirely optional in local realm situations. However, it's a good idea to use one and, if you editing objects, it then allows you to [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/read-and-write-data/#upsert-an-object) them which is what your code is attempting to do here `add(category, update: .all)` which requires a primary key. Please review the [Read and Write](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/read-and-write-data/) guide as it will clear up a lot of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of this is covered in the Realm guide [Read and Write Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/read-and-write-data/) but let me also provide some details. Note, this answer reflects Swift pre-10.10.0 and some things have changed in later versions.

The method you're trying to use

```
realm.add(category, update: .all)
```

is called an 'upsert' and requires a primary key in the object.

> An upsert either inserts or updates an object depending on whether the
> object already exists. Upserts require the data model to have a
> primary key.

So let's re-tool the Category object to include a primary key _id

```
class Category: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let items = List<Item>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}
```

Then, when an object is created

```
let newCategory = Category()
newCategory.name = textField.text!
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(newCategory)
}
```

it will have a primary key

From then forward you can either modify the object within a write or upsert it via it's primary key.

```
let someId = //the id of the newCategory created above
try! realm.write {
   let anotherCat = Category(value: ["_id": someId, "name": "Frank"])
   realm.add(anotherCat, update: .modified)
}
```

The above code will update the original newCategory object with a new name because the _id is the same

Comment: thanks for answer, but when I try that I get the following error: Attempting to create an object of type 'Category' with an existing primary key value '60fb33c9c687b78540419c61'.'

Comment: @LukaVujnovac Whoops. Had the object initialization in the wrong place. It should be inside the write. I have corrected the code.